# Did prophet Mohammad (PBUH) split the moon?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, miracles

It is widely believed in Islam that Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) spit the moon.

Is there any scientific evidence found by the astronauts or astronomers or scientists in favor of that belief?

Comment: Does splitting the moon necessarily mean a physical split?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are a site about Islam, not about astronomy.